# While and for loop with global variable not working Python updated

Tags: python, function, for-loop, while-loop, global-variables

**Working for single symbol**

```
  todate = zerodha.get_trade_day(datetime.now().astimezone(to_india) - timedelta(days=0))
fromdate = zerodha.get_trade_day(datetime.now().astimezone(to_india) - timedelta(days=5))

symbol = "ZINC20MAYFUT" 

instype = "MCX"     
Timeinterval = "5minute" 

tradeDir =  0 #neutral

while (True):

histdata1 = zerodha.get_history(symbol, fromdate, todate, Timeinterval, instype)
df = pd.DataFrame(histdata1)
df = heikinashi(df)
df = bollinger_bands(df,field='h_close',period=20, numsd=2)
df1 =pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['date','volume','close','h_close','middle_band', 'upper_band'])
pp = pd.DataFrame(df1.tail(3))
print(pp)

dfCToList = pp['h_close'].tolist()
dfCList = list(pp['h_close'])
dfHValues = pp['h_close'].values
dfBMValues = pp['middle_band'].values
H_last = dfHValues[2]  # tail 1
BM_last = dfBMValues[2]  # tail 1

if (H_last > BM_last and (tradeDir == 0 or tradeDir == -1)):
    print("buy")
    tradeDir = 1  # up

if (H_last < BM_last and (tradeDir == 0 or tradeDir == 1)):
    print("SELL")
    tradeDir = -1  # down

# pdb.set_trace()
```

**Question: When conditions meet its Printing "BUY/SELL" again and again. I want to just print a single time when condition meet the first time**

```
todate = zerodha.get_trade_day(datetime.now().astimezone(to_india) - timedelta(days=0))
fromdate = zerodha.get_trade_day(datetime.now().astimezone(to_india) - timedelta(days=5))
tradeDir =  0 #neutral

def script():
    global tradeDir
    ##For historical Data##
    symbol = ["ZINC20MAYFUT" ,"CRUDEOIL20MAYFUT","GOLD20JUNFUT"]
    instype = "MCX"     
    Timeinterval = "5minute" 

for symbol in symbol:
    global tradeDir
    histdata1 = zerodha.get_history(symbol, fromdate, todate, Timeinterval, instype)
    df = pd.DataFrame(histdata1)
    df = heikinashi(df)
    df = bollinger_bands(df,field='h_close',period=20, numsd=2)
    df1 =pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['date','volume','close','h_close','middle_band', 'upper_band'])
    pp = pd.DataFrame(df1.tail(3))
    print(pp)
    dfCToList = pp['h_close'].tolist()
    dfCList = list(pp['h_close'])
    dfHValues = pp['h_close'].values
    dfBMValues = pp['middle_band'].values
    H_last = dfHValues[2]  # tail 1
    BM_last = dfBMValues[2]  # tail 1

    if (H_last > BM_last and (tradeDir == 0 or tradeDir == -1)):
        print("buy")
        tradeDir = 1  # up

    if (H_last < BM_last and (tradeDir == 0 or tradeDir == 1)):
        print("SELL")
        tradeDir = -1  # down

    # pdb.set_trace()

while True:
    try:
        script()
    except Exception as e:
        sleep(2)
        continue
```

When conditions meet its Printing "BUY/SELL" again and again. I want to just print a single time when condition meet the first time full Script and should run continuously

Comment: You really must clean up the code sample you provided. The preceding `>` characters are a real pain to read through, but even worse, there are line feeds missing, and automatic line breaks that should not be there. A Python interpreter would not be able to read this code (even with the `>` removed), so stack overflow should not be required to.

Comment: Hi @AmitaiIrron I have posted updated code format, please suggest

Comment: The logic of the program is not clear. You seem to be iterating through symbols, and computing independent trading parameters for each of them. However, you then use the global variable `tradeDir` to access historical data and print recommendation based on that. The data in `tradeDir` is, therefore, one that links between symbols. Perhaps you wanted to maintain a dictionary of trade directions for each symbol?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code to stop looping after the first time it prints "buy" or "SELL", you just need to add a `break` statement after each of the prints (inside the scope of the containing `if` blocks).

Comment: Thanks. I want  If there is BUY turn to SELL it print sell at first one and similarly if SELL turn to BUY it only print BUY once and loop to continue find pattern of buy or SELL